# Указатели Си,среднее арифметическое

Tags: c, указатели

Почему не работает?Задача состоит в нахождении среднего арифметического с помощью указателей.
Выдаёт Segmentation fault (core dumped)

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    float main() {
    float* a ;
    float* b ;
    float* c ;
    float* res;
    scanf("%float", a);
    scanf("%float", b);
    scanf("%float", c);
    *res = (float)(*a + *b + *c) / 3;
    printf("%f\n", *res);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: А куда они, эти указатели, указывают?

Comment: должны бы на a,b,c и указывать

Comment: Нет, они указывают куда попало. Прежде чем что-то писать по адресу, содержащемуся в указателe, следует распределить соответствующее количество памяти и присвоить указателю значение, чтобы он на эту распределенную память указывал.

Comment: float* a = (float*)malloc(sizeof(a)); ?

Comment: не, не стоит так делать.  лучше просто пишите `float a; scanf("%f", &a);`

Comment: не совсем понимаю.  вместо (float* a = (float*)malloc(sizeof(a))) нужно (float a; scanf("%f", &a);)????

Comment: @zer3pk42, да. Вам просто задание тупое дали. Формально, взятие адреса `&` тоже подходит под формулировку «используя указатели», поэтому сделайте как написал KoVadim.

Comment: @zer3pk42, ваш вариант с `malloc` тоже будет работать, но так лучше не делать.

Comment: можете продемонстрировать это как рабочий код,пожалуйста,все равно ошибку даёт,даже с методом KoVadim..

Comment: И почему так лучше не делать?

Comment: @zer3pk42, смотрите ответ Harry.

Comment: @zer3pk42, нет смысла динамически выделять память через `malloc` там, где можно обойтись локальными переменными. Во-первых, это гораздо медленнее. Во-вторых, эту память нужно вручную освобождать. В-третьих, так никто не делает. Можно привести еще много причин, но вы и сами поймете, что так делать не нужно, когда с опытом у вас появится интуитивное понимание всего происходящего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, если только указатели...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  float a, b, c,
    *pa = &a, *pb = &b, *pc = &c;

  if (scanf("%f %f %f", pa, pb, pc) == 3)
    printf("%f\n", (*pa + *pb + *pc) / 3);
  else
    puts("input error");

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Конечно, память можно было бы и `malloc()`-м выделить, например, вот так
`float *pa = malloc(sizeof(float) * 3),*pb = pa + 1, *pc = pa + 2;`
но решил не усложнять пример для новичка

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {   // int, не float!!
    float a, b, c, res;
    scanf("%f", &a);  // Не %float!
    scanf("%f", &b);
    scanf("%f", &c);
    res = (a + b + c) / 3;
    printf("%f\n", res);
}
```

Ну, [держите указатели](https://ideone.com/pGXipF)...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {   // int, не float!!
    float *a = malloc(2*sizeof(float));
    *(a+1) = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%f", a);  // Не %float!
        *(a+1) += *a;
    }
    printf("%f\n", *(a+1)/3);
    free(a);
}
```

Comment: (Найти среднее арифметическое из трех чисел, используя только указатели)

Comment: Да без проблем, добавил...

Comment: так там сказано, используя только указатели. А я вижу сложение, деление...